# Exclude post if post contains "good" word

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to implement a feature that, If post description contains "good" word then `exclude` it from all the posts.

views.py

```
def posts(request):
   posts = Post.objects.all()

    if 'good'  in posts.description:
        printing = 'CONTAINS'


    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'mains/posts.html', context)
```

From this view, I am just trying to print the `contains` word in template ( just for test and It's working fine ) BUT I am trying to exclude that post ( which contains good word ) from all the posts.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: This `if 'good'  in posts.description:` does not give you an error? `posts` is a queryset here not an instance of `Post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude objects from a queryset using the [`exclude` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) method and to check for objects containing some string you can use the [`contains` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains) lookup (or the `icontains` lookup (case insensitive)):

```
posts = Post.objects.exclude(description__contains='good')
```

Edit: If you want to exclude multiple values then you can use [Q objects [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q


posts = Post.objects.exclude(Q(description__contains='good') | Q(description__contains='good1') | Q(description__contains='good2'))
```

Comment: AND what if i want to `exclude two words from the list` ? Lke if a `posts.description` contains word `good` and `good1` ?

Comment: @TEST check my edit, although do note, [questions that keep changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are frowned upon in Stack Overflow.

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. IT WORKED. Can i `exclude two different things at posts query` ?

Comment: @TEST what do you mean by that? If you mean you want to exclude according to some other field also then yes you can do that.